# Splitting strings into components

Tags: r, parsing, extract

For example, I have a data table with several columns:

```
column A                      column B
key_500:station and loc       2
spectra:key_600:type          9
alpha:key_100:number          12
```

I want to split the rows of column A into components and create new columns, guided by the following rules:

- the value between "`key_`" and "`:`" will be `var1`,
- the next value after "`:`" will be `var2`,
- the original `column A` should retain the part of string that is prior to "`:key_`". If it is empty (as in the first line), then replace `""` with an "`effect`" word.

My expected final data table should be like this one:

```
column A   column B  var1  var2
effect     2         500   station and loc
spectra    9         600   type
alpha      12        100   number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyr` `extract` you can extract specific part of the string using regex.

```
tidyr::extract(df, columnA, into = c('var1', 'var2'), 'key_(\\d+):(.*)', 
               convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(columnA = sub(':?key_.*', '', columnA), 
         columnA = replace(columnA, columnA == '', 'effect'))

#  columnA var1            var2 columnB
#1  effect  500 station and loc       2
#2 spectra  600            type       9
#3   alpha  100          number      12
```

If you want to use `data.table` you can break this down in steps :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, c('var1', 'var2') := .(sub('.*key_(\\d+).*', '\\1',columnA), 
                            sub('.*key_\\d+:', '', columnA))]
df[, columnA := sub(':?key_.*', '', columnA)]
df[, columnA := replace(columnA, columnA == '', 'effect')]
```

**data**

```
df <-  structure(list(columnA = c("key_500:station and loc", 
"spectra:key_600:type", "alpha:key_100:number"), 
columnB = c(2L, 9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Could you, please, indicate, what regex expression should I use in case I have string like this: `alpha:key_100:number:gamma`? I mean, what should be the third part with `sub` here: `df[, c('var1', 'var2', 'var3') := .(sub('.*key_(\\d+).*', '\\1',columnA), sub('.*key_\\d+:', '', columnA), sub(, columnA))]`?

Comment: In such case then why not split string on `:` and create new columns. `do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$columnA, ':'))`. You can drop the columns that you don't want.

Comment: But in this case I'll lose value near the `key_`

Comment: No...you don't lose the value near `key_` you need to remove `key_` using `sub` from the second column to get the value. Also you can do this easily with `extract` approach in my answer. Change the `into` part to `into = c('var1', 'var2', 'var3')` and use regex as `'key_(\\d+):(.*?):(.*)'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` which uses non-letters and separates the string into columns defined in `into`

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
df=tribble(
  ~"column A",~"column B",
  "key_500:station",               2,
  "spectra:key_600:type",          9,
  "alpha:key_100:number",          12)
df %>% separate("column A",into=c('column A','key','var1','var2'),fill='left') %>% select(-key) %>% select("column A","column B",var1,var2) %>% 
  mutate(`column A`=ifelse(is.na(`column A`),"effect",`column A`))
```

And this is a modified version to work with data.tables

```
require(tidyr)
require(data.table)
DT=data.table(
  "column A"=
  c("key_500:station and loc",               
  "spectra:key_600:type",          
  "alpha:key_100:number"),          
  "column B"=c(2,9,12))
DT=separate(sep = "[^[:alnum:] ]+",DT,"column A",into=c('column A','key','var1','var2'),fill='left') 
DT$key=NULL
DT$`column A`=ifelse(is.na(DT$`column A`),"effect",DT$`column A`)
DT=DT[,c(1,4,2,3)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But initially, for example, on the first row, I have no value before the `key_`. The `effect` should be added only after parsing the strings into different columns. How can this be done using the `date.table` approach?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this part , I've added my code, to fill the missing pieces, but it requires dplyr/tidyr packages. The tribble is not really needed, I only use it to create a data.frame. And I think data.table is similar to data.frame